# How to mock event object in React/Typescript with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to test that the console.log function is being called when the user presses the Enter key by an interactive HTMLElement. I've been trying to mock an event object of the function bellow in Jest with Typescript but it is not working. How to mock event object in  React/Typescript with Jest?

**Example:**

```
import React from 'react';

function handleKey(event: React.KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('The enter key has been clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event#keyboardtext-options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the handler is a publicly consumable function, then call it with a plain object (you might have to do a type assertion)

```js
console.log = jest.fn();
handleKey({ key: 'Enter' } as React.KeyboardEvent);
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('The enter key has been clicked');
```

If the handler you are testing is inside a component, you can call it indirectly by firing a keydown or keypress on the element that triggers the handler.

If you are using React Testing library, use [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireevent)

```
const myInput = getByTestId(container, 'my-input')
fireEvent.keyPress(myInput, { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 })
```

If you are using Enzyme, use [simulate](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html)

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'})
```

If RTL has issues with keypress, refer to https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/269

Comment: I would like to thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, in my case, I have to mock that event object. I know that it is a bad practice and I do not have to use it. Maybe that's the reason why there are no examples of such cases.

Comment: Indeed! I got you.